# mapStateToProps returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { login, logout } from "./redux/actions/accounts";
import Home from "./Home";
import Login from "./Login";

class Switch extends Component {
  render() {
    const { boolean } = this.props;
    return <Fragment>{boolean ? Home : Login}</Fragment>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  boolean: true
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login, logout })(Switch);
```

I have a Simple Switch Component and even after Stripping it down to the bone(literally), it doesn't return a state to the Component. Please Forgive me For the Bad Code.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning valid react element.

```
return <Fragment>{boolean ? Home : Login}</Fragment>;
```

should be

```
return <Fragment>{boolean ? <Home /> : <Login />}</Fragment>;
```

Here's a working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-64gywo)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import Switch component as default.